# Checking big O expression in Wolfram Alpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I'd like to check the expression x<sup>3</sup>=O(x<sup>2</sup>) when x → 0 in Wolfram Alpha.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, one of the [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) uses a limit: x<sup>3</sup>=O(x<sup>2</sup>) if and only if the limit when x → 0 of x<sup>3</sup>/x<sup>2</sup> exists.

And [it does](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x-%3E0+x%5E3%2Fx%5E2):

[image]

Comment: Hello @Glorfindel than you very much for your answer. I'm looking for a symbol or a function because I need to do operations like O(x^2)+O(x^3)

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi I understand but I'm not sure that's possible. Wolfram Alpha isn't Mathematica after all ...